# select to group rows

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a table like this :

```
Alternative |Total  |Male  |Female
a           |20     |10    |10
b           |50     |20    |30 
c           |40     |10    |30 
c           |30     |15    |15
```

now I want to select all the rows and the "c" alternative to be grouped.

Comment: What do you mean by grouped? What results do you want back?

Comment: @Ed Harper: I also had that suspicion.

Comment: What a gloriously ironic username, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will select all the rows that are not "c", then group all the rows that are "c", sum their value, and add a single row representing the sum of "c". I hope that's what you mean.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE Alternative != c

UNION

SELECT Alternative, Sum(Total) as Total, Sum(Male) as Male, Sum(Female) as Female
FROM table1 
WHERE Alternative = c
GROUP BY Alternative
```

If you just want to group anything that has multiple "Alternative" appearances, just use:

```
SELECT Alternative, Sum(Total) as Total, Sum(Male) as Male, Sum(Female) as Female
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Alternative
```

Comment: Well...that's definitely taking a literal view of the question.

Comment: @TheTXI: I assumed this is not a "what's the syntax of group by / how do i group items" question, but rather a more advanced one. I

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Alternative, Sum(Total), Sum(Male), Sum(Female) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Alternative
```

Comment: This will also sum the values that are not C, I'm not sure that's what he wants. See my answer below.

Comment: I'm well aware of that Rax. It has been my experience from using SO that often times a question-asker doesn't always know how to correctly phrase their question. If it turns out that yours is what he wants, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice

```
SELECT Alternative, [Total] = SUM(Total), [Male] = SUM(Male), [Female] = SUM(Female)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Alternative
```

Comment: I had to read the question several times before I understood what the OP wanted.

Comment: Only thing I didn't bother with were the column aliases on the sums and the order by clause that the other poster put below this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` to determine the grouping, then use the appropriate aggregate to process the other fields. I believe in this case that you want to use `sum` to add the values in each group:

```
select
   Alternative, sum(Total) as Total, sum(Male) as Male, sum(Female) as Female
from
   TheTable
group by
   Alternative
order by
   Alternative
```